# C++ How to insert a char into vector

Tags: c++

I have a vector declared like following:

```
    vector < vector<char> > v;
```

Depend of player I would like to insert x or o into vector. I am doing it like this:

```
 v[y][x]= set%2 ? 'o':'x';
```

In my vector instead o or x I am getting: 120 'x'. Why? What should I do to insert only x?

Comment: are these vectors fixed size or do they expand and shrink?

Comment: how are you printing the char?

Comment: What do you mean by "I am getting 120 'x'"?

Comment: the char 'x' has value 120

Comment: @ us2012 In debugger I get such value: {move=0 win=false v=[2]([2](120 'x',0),[2](0,0)) }game_size* const

Comment: @Natalia That's just the debugger trying to be helpful. It gives you the decimal value of the char as well as the character representation. This can be useful, because you can use `char` as a numeric type if you want, and then you actually want the decimal value.

Comment: @Rubens I am not printing this.

Comment: @Natalia In other words, there is nothing wrong with your code. Your `v[y][x]` is still simply `'x'` - just try printing it and you'll see.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that you're most  probably printing the char as an integer, which would give you 120 for 'x'. See the [ascii table](http://www.asciitable.com/).

As pointed by @us2012, considering your comment about how you're seeing the value:

> In debugger I get such value: {move=0 win=false v=[2]([2](120 'x',0),2) }game_size* const

This is just the debugger showing extra information.

If you want to print the value, you can choose the exact representation -- either using `printf` parameters, or by `static_cast`'ing what you want to print.

Printing with:

```
std::cout << v[y][x] << std::endl;
```

will give you 'x', since the vector stores a `char`.

In case you want to see it in decimal, simply use:

```
std::cout << static_cast<int>(v[y][x]) << std::endl;
```